# Should I put default value in database?

Tags: database-design

Assuming most users won't set up their avatars is it better to store a value like default.jpg in user's table avatar column while creating new user or to check for existence of value in controller/view and if it's null display the default one?

Comment: I would leave it empty, and perform the check via code. It feels cleaner, and leaves me the option of changing from, say `default.jpg` to `default.png` at a later date without having to touch the database.

Comment: @ArjunShankar: +1 just what I was going to say, you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @casablanca - Right. Done now. There really were only two possible answers to this one, which is why I was hesitant to write one down.

Comment: @ArjunShankar: Such questions generally have no "correct" answer, so there is no need to be hesitant. You should only exercise caution if your answer might be misleading or downright incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would leave it empty, and perform the check via code.

1. It leaves me the option of changing from, say `default.jpg` to `default.png` at a later date without having to touch the database. Or doing other fun stuff, [like how SO generates 'default' avatars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20472/179533).
2. It *feels* cleaner to me (The user *didn't* choose an avatar. Therefore, empty field. If the user didn't enter her age, would you make one up? No.)

By the way, you really should check out [gravatar.com](http://gravatar.com) before implementing yet another avatar. I love it that I need to upload my avatar just once to one website and all other sites (like SO) automatically use it.

Comment: thank you for answer. considering the pros and cons i think this solution will be better for me. and the idea of generating random default avatars is pretty nice. i have last one question: should i set the default avatar in my model and pass it to controller or should i do it in the controller itself? which is more mvc-like?

Comment: I'd say producing a 'default' avatar comes under business logic. So putting it in the model makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with having your "create new user" method put the `default.jpg` in the database. This keeps things consistent in your users table so your code doesn't have to do checks or handle special cases when the field is empty. It also gives you just one place in your code where you have to keep track of it.

When you're creating the user is when you want to be doing your validations and checks and prevent/fix things where necessary. The further down the line you let this trickle down into the harder it gets to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Putting NULL in the database saves storage as opposed to having many identical (and therefore redundant) default.jpg BLOBs.

Of course, you might be storing images in a filesystem, in which case storage savings would be much more modest (since only the file path would be repeated, not the file itself). Or you could devise a way for BLOBs to be shared among users. But all these strategies complicate querying and possibly impact performance/integrity...